# "ACTION REQUIRED: Drive web hosting is shutting down"

Tags: google-drive-api

Google sent me this confusing message:

> Hello Google Apps Developer,
>
> We announced last year that we¿re deprecating Google Drive web hosting for users and developers. On Aug 31, 2016, the service will be shut down and websites that are hosted via googledrive.com/host/[id] will become unavailable.
>
> We noticed that the following apps are still hosting files via googledrive.com/host/[id]:
>
> 976243706349

The number 976243706349 was not directly useful - I had to go through all my projects on console.developers.google.com to find the one that had 976243706349 in its OAuth client ID. They could have at least provided a working link...

Even after identifying the project, I don't know what this message is trying to tell me. I don't think I've ever seen the googledrive.com/host/ URL before, and if I put the ID number in there:

https://googledrive.com/host/976243706349

I just get a 404 error page.

How can I find these "hosted files" they're talking about?

If the question seems out of place (and I think it does), blame google for shifting customer support here. The message ended like this:

> If you have additional questions, please see [Stack Overflow](http://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/R7HGZlBngphKj2wyWTUFFAT5gOzuo8dUMQdGSy0vIaqZcBQaCjwjataCJnWP_Q23xdhQ3Z0TbxG-Ta7ZkQ9KExW4YJQKT3MwiiAV).

Comment: This says the project with this ID has some data on Google Drive web hosting, and after 31.08.2016 that app will get a 404/500, depending on how they handle shutting down. Or, "Choose another web hosting".

Comment: I have never, as far as I know used "google drive web hosting", or even heard of it. I don't know what it is. My project uses the Picker API, if that helps. And the Drive API is enabled in the project, but only because it was enabled by default and I didn't disable it.

Comment: Probably you have once used the link to test that Google service, they recorded it and even if there are no files under that folder (it's a folder, so add another slash after the number), they still warn you about possible loss of data. Can't tell anything else, maybe other would help.

Comment: I think this [link](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html) can help you. It shows here how to identify the active use of Drive web hosting in the domain. The Google Apps admins can use the [Account activity](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580176) reports in the Admin console. These reports can pinpoint users who own items that are publicly shared in order for Admins to contact and assist them with [alternate solutions](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2016/07/reminder-turn-down-of-google-drive-web.html).